# RTSP Authentication : digest issue

Tags: authentication, streaming, rtsp, http-authentication, digest-authentication

I need to authenticate my RTSP stream to a streaming server, here is the challenge :

```
RTSP/1.0 401 Unauthorized
WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="Streaming Server",  nonce="76bfe6986d3e766424de9bd6e7d3ccc1"
Session: 1845562184;timeout=60
Cseq: 1
...
```

Wirecast manage to successfully authenticate with those settings :

```
Host name : 192.168.33.9:1935/live/my_stream.sdp
location : live/my_stream.sdp
username : user
password : test
```

its response is : e1dff363b9763df0c7615429af79715c

So according to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication) I tried to authenticate with the method :

```
//H(data) = MD5(data)
//KD(secret, data) = H(secret:data)
//A1 = username:realm:password
//A2 = http-method:uri
//response = KD( H(A1), nonce:H(A2))

HA1 = md5("user:Streaming Server:test")
HA2 = md5("POST:live/my_stream.sdp")
RESPONSE = md5(HA1+":"+nonce+":"+HA2)
```

but with this code I get the response "0963c3a7b1481523f809e6affa7e792e" and 401 Unauthorized

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your digest method is fine you can try to answer with those parameters :

```
Authorization: Digest
username="user",
realm="Streaming Server",
nonce="76bfe6986d3e766424de9bd6e7d3ccc1",
uri="/live/my_stream.sdp",
```

Comment: This is definitely wrong, because it doesn't contain the calculated `response` hash.

Comment: Also the uri should be localpath, which is in this case "/live/my_stream.sdp"

Comment: @Matyas: The specs say "per HTTP 1.1", which allows absolute paths. The main thing is that the Authorization response contains both the plaintext uri and the hashed response; they obviously should match.

Answer (score 8):

The calculation of the response should be:

```
HA1 = md5("user:Streaming Server:test")
HA2 = md5("DESCRIBE:/live/my_stream.sdp")
RESPONSE = md5(HA1+":"+nonce+":"+HA2)
```

And the complete authentication string:

```
Authorization: Digest
username="user",
algorithm="MD5",
realm="Streaming Server",
nonce="76bfe6986d3e766424de9bd6e7d3ccc1",
uri="/live/my_stream.sdp",
response="de73283590f7ad76929d20f0d06e914b"
```

Comment: That is to say: `HA2` should use the **RTSP verb**. The question says "HTTP verb" because it refers to HTTP authentication, but RTSP has different verbs.