# rtsp authentication : digest

Tags: authentication, rtsp

I am trying to connect with a camera sending a RTSP stream, but I'm having some trouble with authentication. To begin with i was sending the message

```
SENDING MESSAGE:
 DESCRIBE rtsp://admin:password@192.169.1.100:554 RTSP/1.0
 CSeq: 100
 User-Agent: askapps server
```

And I got the response

```
RESPONSE FROM CAMERA:
 RTSP/1.0 401 Unauthorized
 CSeq: 100
 WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="Login to OVP42739875923", nonce="ca0b6e51ff51c0cfbe523935da1a07dd"
```

Using links as wikipedia and [RTSP Authentication : digest issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17444635/rtsp-authentication-digest-issue), I tried

```
SENDING MESSAGE:
 DESCRIBE rtsp://admin:password@192.168.8.100 RTSP/1.0
 CSeq: 1
 Authorization: Digest
 username="admin",
 algorithm="MD5",
 realm="OVP42739875923",
 nonce="ca0b6e51ff51c0cfbe523935da1a07dd",
 uri="rtsp://192.168.8.101:554",
 response="ce145f3e1e7d9827e1977d8f6b4c6c01"
```

Which simple resulted in the message

```
RESPONSE FROM CAMERA:
RTSP/1.0 401 Unauthorized
CSeq: 1
```

I was wondering if you could help? maybe if you have a link or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what I needed.

What was wrong was that I did not update the nonce, but used the same again and again. This means that you need to first send a request to without the label 'Authenticate'. It will then give you the realm and nonce, which you should use as authentication. Again see the question, which are linked in the question.